# How to create page-locked memory from a existing numpy array in PyCUDA?

Tags: pycuda

The [PyCUDA help explains how to create an empty or zeroed array](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pagelocked-allocation) but not how to move(?) an existing numpy array into page-locked memory. Do I need to get a pointer for the numpy array and pass it to `pycuda.driver.PagelockedHostAllocation`? And how would I do that?

**UPDATE**

<--sniped -->

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks **talonmies** for you help. Now the memory transfare is page-locked but the program ends with the following error:

```
PyCUDA WARNING: a clean-up operation failed (dead context maybe?)
cuMemFreeHost failed: invalid context
```

This is the updated code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import numpy as np
import ctypes
from pycuda import driver, compiler, gpuarray
from pycuda.tools import PageLockedMemoryPool
import pycuda.autoinit

memorypool = PageLockedMemoryPool()

indata = np.random.randn(5).astype(np.float32)
outdata = gpuarray.zeros(5, dtype=np.float32)

pinnedinput = memorypool.allocate(indata.shape,np.float32)

source = indata.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
dest = pinnedinput.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
sz = indata.size * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float)
ctypes.memmove(dest,source,sz)


kernel_code = """
 __global__ void kernel(float *indata, float *outdata) {
 int globalid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ;
 outdata[globalid] = indata[globalid]+1.0f;

 }
 """

mod = compiler.SourceModule(kernel_code)
kernel = mod.get_function("kernel")

kernel(
 driver.In(pinnedinput), outdata,
 grid = (5,1),
 block = (1, 1, 1),
)
print indata
print outdata.get()
memorypool.free_held()
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to copy the data from your source array to the array holding the page locked allocation returned from pycuda. The most straightforward way to do that is via `ctypes`:

```
import numpy
import ctypes

x=numpy.array([1,2,3,4],dtype=numpy.double)
y=numpy.zeros_like(x)

source = x.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
dest = y.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
sz = x.size * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_double)

ctypes.memmove(dest,source,sz)

print y
```

The `numpy.ctypes` interface can be used to get a pointer to the memory used to hold an arrays data, and then the `ctypes.memmove` used to copy between two different ndarrays. All the usual caveats of working with naked C pointers apply, so some care is required, but it is straightforward enough to use.

Answer (score 1):

The memory block is still active. You might explicitly free the pinned array:

```
print memorypool.active_blocks
pinnedinput.base.free()
print memorypool.active_blocks
memorypool.free_held()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this in a much simpler way:

```
locked_ary = cuda.pagelocked_empty_like(ary, mem_flags=cuda.host_alloc_flags.DEVICEMAP)
locked_ary[:] = ary
```

The result has the right `AlignedHostAllocation` base, and timings are identical to what I get by using `ctypes.memmove`.